# springboot manually commit after each call to Stored Procedure

Tags: spring-boot, transactions, simplejdbccall

I have a springboot application that needs to iterate over a large number of records and call a stored procedure which inserts some data in a table for each record read.

we cannot use BatchUpdate because it is taking a long time to process thousands of records , I was asked to commit frequently (either after every record or after x records)

I was looking online and I did not see a good example on how to commit manually in springboot while calling a stored procedure in a loop.
I am using SimpleJdbcCall and my code looks like this:

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED,propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public class EventsProcessor 
{

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dbDatasource")
    DataSource dataSource;

    public void process(List<Event> events) throws Exception
    {       
             SimpleJdbcCall dbTemplate = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource).withProcedureName("UPDATE_EVENTS").withSchemaName("TEST");
             DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource).setAutoCommit(false);
             for (Event ev : events)
             {
                   //fill inParams here
                   outParams =  dbTemplate.execute(inParams);
                   DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource).commit();
             }
    }


}
```

I tried without Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED and with it but same result.
The code is executing the call to the sp and there is not error when it executes commit() , but after commit() if I query the table that the sp inserted the record in it, I don't see the records in the table.

If I remove the setAutocommit(false) and the commit statement and the Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED , and just let springboot handle transactions, then while it's processing, I can see the records in the table if I do READ UNCOMMITTED, but they will not be committed till the full job ends.
What am I doing wrong that is preventing the commit to happen after each row?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up separating the call to the SP into a different method with

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

This way when it returns from the method, it commits.